# Show button if input is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not much of a JavaScript guru, so I would need help with a simple code.
I have a button that clears the value of an input field.

I would like it (the button) to be hidden if input field is empty and vice versa (visible if there is text inside the input field).

The solution can be pure JavaScript or jQuery, it doesn't matter. The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(!$('input').val()){
    $('#button').hide();
}
else {
    $('#button').show();
}
```

In it's simplest form ;)

Comment: yes indeed :D Is there even a shorter way? Im trying to do it with .toggle().

Comment: Well maybe you could make it shorter, yes, but why? Oh, from past experience I reccomend not getting used to using .toggle(). Could cause problems in the future when working with more complicated code. Imagine something causes the function to initiate twice for some reason, the toggle will work twice. If you use .hide() then the element is told to be hidden twice, no big deal right?

Comment: Yea, you are right :D I was just wondering if it is possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
   if ($(this).val()) {
      $("button").show();
   }
   else {
      $("button").hide();
   }
});
$("button").click(function () {
   $("input").val('');
   $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/

Comment: Are we encouraged or discouraged to provide full solutions like this? (I'm neither here nor there - just curious what the stance is on SO)

Comment: @SergioTapia this is not really a "full" solution -- I think it's quite bare bones.  It uses general selectors and doesn't care what the value of the input is .. it doesn't even account for hiding the button initially (which I would do with css).

Comment: I would rather use "onchange" since you want to trigger the toggling only if the text is changed (you can press many buttons without actually triggering the onchange event).

Comment: @Styxxy `.onchange` will not fire in some browsers until the input loses focus.

Comment: True that, tested it myself. In that case, you'll indeed have to use the key* event(s).

Answer (score 2):

to do this without jQuery (essentially the same thing others already did, just pure js). It's pretty simple, but I've also added a few comments.

```
 <body>
    <input type="text" id="YourTextBox" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="YourButton" value="Click Me" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var textBox = null;
        var button = null;

        var textBox_Change = function(e) {
            // just calls the function that sets the visibility
            button_SetVisibility();
        };

        var button_SetVisibility = function() {
            // simply check if the visibility is set to 'visible' AND textbox hasn't been filled
            // if it's already visibile and the text is blank, hide it
            if((button.style.visibility === 'visible') && (textBox.value === '')) {
                button.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else {
                // show it otherwise
                button.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        };    

        var button_Click = function(e) {
            // absolutely not required, just to add more to the sample
            // this will set the textbox to empty and call the function that sets the visibility
            textBox.value = '';  
            button_SetVisibility();
        };                

        // wrap the calls inside anonymous function
        (function() {
            // define the references for the textbox and button here
            textBox = document.getElementById("YourTextBox");
            button = document.getElementById("YourButton");
            // some browsers start it off with empty, so we force it to be visible, that's why I'll be using only chrome for now on...
            if('' === button.style.visibility) { button.style.visibility = 'visible'; }
            // assign the event handlers for the change and click event
            textBox.onchange = textBox_Change;
            button.onclick = button_Click;
            // initialize calling the function to set the button visibility
            button_SetVisibility();
        })();
    </script>
</body>​
```

Note: I've written and tested this in IE9 and Chrome, make sure you test it in other browsers. Also, I've added [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/bYacR/) so you can see it working.

Answer (score 1):

First hide the button on page load:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myButton").hide();
});
```

Then attach an `onChange` handler, which will hide the button whenever the contents of the text-field are empty. Otherwise, it shows the button:

```
jQuery("#myText").change(function() {
    if(this.value.replace(/\s/g, "") === "") {
       jQuery("#myButton").hide();
    } else {
       jQuery("#myButton").show();
    }
});
```

You will also need to hide the button after clearing the input:

```
jQuery("#myButton").click(function() {
   jQuery("#myInput").val("");
   jQuery(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: why do you use `jQuery()` still? Haven't you moved on to `$` yet?

Comment: Force of habit. `$` can be bound to other stuff like Prototype, so I generally just end up using `jQuery`.

Comment: That makes since.  I usually just use jquery, so i don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('selector').hide()` to hide an element from view and `$('selector').show()` to display it again.

Even better, you can use `$('selector').toggle()` to have it show and hide without any custom logic.