# show a button when i check if at least one input is completed and hide the same button when the input == null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to show a button when I check if at least one input is completed and hide the same button when the input == null. This is my file...

```js
ACC.multiLogin = {
        _autoload: [
            "inputField"

        ],

        inputField: function(){
            $("#multiLogin-search input").on('input', function(){
                var input = false;
                $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).val() != null) {
                        input = true;
                        $("#button-row").removeClass("d-none");
                    } else if($(this).val() == "") {
                        input = true;
                        //$("#button-row").removeClass("#button-row");
                        $("#button-row").addClass("d-none");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body> 


<form id="multiLogin-search" class="d-none">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Customer number <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerCode"  > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Country <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="country"  > <p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Postal Code <p>
                    
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="postalCode"  > <p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Customer Name <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerName" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> City <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="city" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Address <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="address"><p>
                </div>
            </div>

            

            <div id="button-row" class='d-none'>
                <button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: On page load as well you want the button to be hidden based on input values?

Comment: Yes, and i want to put any value in input to show the button. When i clear inputs, the button will be hidden.

Comment: Have a look at my code below. Let me know if that suits your purpose

Comment: If i've in the place of class, id in this div:                                                                                  <div class="button-row" class='d-none'>
                <button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search">Button</button>
            </div>                                                                                                                     How can i write     class='d-none' ?

Comment: If you want to use class instead of id simply use $('.button-row').show(), $('.button-row').hide(). If you want to use the other class simply replace ('.button-row') with ('.d-none')

Comment: I do like this https://jsfiddle.net/2zpLq9uh/1/  . I've one problem ->that i get the button first and after my functions work

Comment: You don't need this first line any more - $("#multiLogin-search input").on('input', function()

Comment: I've another button in this form. Now they hide and show together

Comment: Does the another button has the same class & id. If yes assign a new Id & class to it

Comment: They have the same class but type and name are differents

Comment: Can up add the details here. based on that we can update the scripts

Comment: You can lokk this https://jsfiddle.net/fm1y5c8v/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defined the checking as an arrow function and is called on each keyup event in the input.

On page load you can either call the method or just use .hide() as shown below in the snippet.

```js
 var showHideButton = () => {
    let hasValue = false;
    $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").each(function(){
      if ($(this).val()) {
        hasValue = true;
      }
    });
      
    if (hasValue === true) {
      $('#button-row').show();
    } else {
      $('#button-row').hide();
    }
 }
 
 // Check input values on key up
 $("#multiLogin-search input.text-input").keyup(function() { 
   showHideButton();
 });
 
 //To hide button on page load
 showHideButton(); 
 // OR SIMPLEY CALL $('#button-row').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body> 


<form id="multiLogin-search" class="d-none">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Customer number <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerCode"  > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Country <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="country"  > <p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Postal Code <p>
                    
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="postalCode"  > <p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Customer Name <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="customerName" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> City <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="city" > <p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-input-wrap">
                    <p> Address <p>
                    <p> <input class="text-input" type="text" name="address"><p>
                </div>
            </div>

            

            <div id="button-row" class='d-none'>
                <button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search">Button</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's what i searched. It's a best solution

Answer (score 0):

Please check out these.
[Show button if input is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709884/show-button-if-input-is-not-empty/10710873) and
[JavaScript: Hide button link if input field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087376/javascript-hide-button-link-if-input-field-is-empty)

This can get the id of your input and change it to text from hidden.

```
document.getElementById('myElement').type = 'text';
```

You could also use some css to toggle from

```
display: none;
```

and

```
display: block;
```

Comment: I want to hide this button                                                                                                                  <div class="button-row" class='d-none'>
<button class="btn btn-black" type="submit" name="search"><spring:theme code="multilogin.search.button"/></button> </div>

Comment: you you need some JavaScript to change the type of input it is.